# how to change mouse pointer on mouseover a division to hand?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i change the default arrow pointer style to hand when client move the pointer to a particular division?

Comment: i agree with winform answer given by Ardman, but what in case of asp.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WinForm, you can use the `Cursors` class, which provides a collection of Cursor objects. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors.aspx).

But, `Cursor = Cursors.Hand;` will do the job.

**EDIT**

As for ASP .Net, check this [link](http://forums.asp.net/p/681784/682581.aspx) out.  SomeNewKid has posted the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  That is in C#.

Comment: i am calling a code behind function on mouseover a division. want to change the cursor style to hand on call of that function, its in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Dear all, i found the answer as for that division we need to set style, there we have option to set the cursor style.